# Tensorflow ValueError: Only call `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)

Tags: tensorflow

Above error arises from traditional code

```
tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.D_logits_, tf.ones_like(self.D_))
```

And occurs using Tensorflow V1.0 or greater.

The code itself seems error free, how is this fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error itself gives you the fix, you now need to explicitly state which represents the logits and which represents the labels, Tensorflow will no longer assume for you.

This has occured likely because you're working off of outdated code that was written to function before Tensorflow 1.0.

Instead of:

```
(self.D_logits_, tf.ones_like(self.D_))
```

We want:

```
(logits=self.D_logits_, labels=tf.ones_like(self.D_))
```

Updated code:

```
tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.D_logits_, labels=tf.ones_like(self.D_))
```

Thanks to @Mrry who suggested the solution originally here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7814