# Tensorflow ValueError: Only call `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, cross-entropy

When calling the following method:

```
losses = [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
          for logits, labels in zip(logits_series,labels_series)]
```

I receive the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: Only call `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)
```

Against this:

```
[tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
```

According to the documentation for **nn_ops.py** I need to ensure that the logins and labels are initialised to something e.g.:

> def _ensure_xent_args(name, sentinel, labels, logits):   # Make sure
>   that all arguments were passed as named arguments.   if sentinel is
>   not None:
>       raise ValueError("Only call `%s` with "
>                        "named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)" % name)   if labels is None or logits is None:
>       raise ValueError("Both labels and logits must be provided.")
>
> Logits=X, labels =Y

What is the cause here? And am I initialising them to some value such as the loss? Or?

Comment: I found a similar issue here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45038024/tensorflow-valueerror-only-call-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-with

Comment: what do I have to explicitly tell tensorflow what the logits and labels are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that the first argument of [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) is **`_sentinel`**:

> `_sentinel`: Used to prevent positional parameters. Internal, do not use.

This API encourages you to *name* your arguments, like this:

```
tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)
```

... so that you don't accidentally pass `logits` to `labels` or vice versa.

Comment: Ahhh, awesome, fixed. Also, spotted I was passing a float to labels. My bad. 

Cheers for the help on this. Tensorflow is very new to me, so trying to learn amongst all this module shuffling that has happened between 0. and 1. versions.

Comment: No problem, Tensorflow isn't trivial. Don't hesitate to ask further questions when you get confused by something

Comment: @Maxim excuse me , i'm facing this problem and still error exists .. i tried         losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels) with same error .. Can you help, please ?