# Value Error in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/temp/data", one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

# matrix = height * width
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')


# defining the neural network

def neural_network_model(data):
    hiddenLayer1 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                    'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hiddenLayer2 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                    'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hiddenLayer3 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                    'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    outputLayer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                   'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hiddenLayer1['weights']), hiddenLayer1['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hiddenLayer2['weights']), hiddenLayer2['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hiddenLayer3['weights']), hiddenLayer3['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)
    output = tf.matmul(l3, outputLayer['weights']), outputLayer['biases']
    return output


# training the network
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,tf.squeeze(y)))
    #cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y)
    #cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost) * 100
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.003).minimize(cost)

    # cycles feed forward + backprop
    numberOfEpochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

         #dealing with training data
        for epoch in range(numberOfEpochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch', epoch, ' completed out of ', numberOfEpochs, ' loss: ', epoch_loss)

            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
            print('Accuracy: ', accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))


train_neural_network(x)
```

I am new to Tensorflow and I am trying to train my model to read datasets. But every time I run the code, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firstAI.py", line 87, in 
    train_neural_network(x)
  File "firstAI.py", line 62, in train_neural_network
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,tf.squeeze(y)));
  File "/home/phillipus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1935, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    labels, logits)
  File "/home/phillipus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1713, in _ensure_xent_args
    "named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)" % name)
ValueError: Only call `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)

Looks like the problem is at the "**cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,tf.squeeze(y)))**" and the calling of the "**train_neural_network(x)**" function. I am new to Tensorflow so my troubleshooting isn't at its best, anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try using tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits rather than tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits inside the cost calculation.

However, if you want to continue to use tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits then this link might help: [Tensorflow ValueError: Only call `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909606/tensorflow-valueerror-only-call-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-with?rq=1) .

By the way, what are the versions of tensorflow and python you're using?

Try running this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/temp/data", one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

# matrix = height * width
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')


# defining the neural network

def neural_network_model(data):
    hiddenLayer1 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 
            n_nodes_hl1])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hiddenLayer2 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
            'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hiddenLayer3 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    outputLayer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
           'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hiddenLayer1['weights']), hiddenLayer1['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hiddenLayer2['weights']), hiddenLayer2['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hiddenLayer3['weights']), hiddenLayer3['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, outputLayer['weights']),outputLayer['biases'])
    return output


prediction = neural_network_model(x)
cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.003).minimize(cost)

# cycles feed forward + backprop
numberOfEpochs = 10

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

     #dealing with training data
    for epoch in range(numberOfEpochs):
    epoch_loss = 0
    for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)):
        epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
        epoch_loss += c
    print('Epoch', epoch, ' completed out of ', numberOfEpochs, ' loss: ', epoch_loss)

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
    print('Accuracy: ', accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: My python version is 3.6.3 and my tensorflow version is 1.5.0. I tried your suggestion and I got the same exact error

Comment: Try this line to see if it works:
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=tf.squeeze(y)))

Comment: Well let's try some more combinations then, hopefully at some point you won't get any errors and then you can build from there. Try: cost = 
(1) tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y)
(2) the commented line below the one you're trying for cost, does it work? (with and without tf.squeeze(y))

Comment: All failed, I got to say, this is brutal

Comment: Yeah! That's usually how it goes. But you get this code to run, not to worry.
Did you try the cost **without** using tf.reduce_mean for the option (1)? Just:
cost = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y)

Comment: Calling the method train_neural_network(x) seems to be failing too, That is how a method is called in Python yes?

Comment: Yes I did, again... Fails

Comment: It's giving you errors because of the cost calculation. The thing is it looks like you're not adding anything to the function. You have to add the data in there:

train_neural_network(your_data_of_interest)

rather than

train_neural_network(x)

because x is just a placeholder variable

Comment: Oh!!!!!!! That makes sense, how does one pass in the data in the function though?

Comment: That's what I'm researching right now! Try compiling only up to mnist and seeing what it gives you. I'll try on my end to see what it is.

Comment: Up to mnist?? Like my 3rd line??

Comment: Try mnist.train as your input data for train_neural_network(x). That is:
train_neural_network(mnist.train). Or maybe train_neural_network(mnist.train.images)

Comment: If this doesn't work, look at the new edit from the answer!
Try running the code I just added there!

Comment: Okay, trying now

Comment: Oh I see, all you did was remove the function, or is there something else that I missed in the edited code?

Comment: In the last line of neural_network_model function, the output does not have the tf.add() in it, which is important. I've also added the logits= and labels= in the cost line. Did it work?

Comment: The same line shows  the error, but before that it shows the message that I will indicate in my next comment

Comment: Okay, with ALL changes made, the following error comes up

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firstAI.py", line 62, in <module>
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=tf.squeeze(y)));
  File "/home/phillipus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1964, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    precise_logits, labels, name=name)
  File "/home/phillipus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 4804, in _sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    labels=labels, name=name)
That's the first part

Comment: File "/home/phillipus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 609, in _apply_op_helper
    param_name=input_name)
  File "/home/phillipus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'labels' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
the second part

Comment: I just updated the code in my answer! See if that works please!

Comment: What parts were changed?? Trying it now

Comment: I used the commented cost you had (second line below the used cost variable). That was the only change. By the way, you could have added the function like you did originally...I just took it out for personal preference. All the changes I made you can make on your original code. My comment about train_neural_network(x) can be disregarded. I though data was going in, but it was not.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! YOU WERE A HUGE HELP!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH... IT WORKED!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm really glad I could help you Phillipus! Do you mind tagging my answer as the correct one? Try implementing the changes I made in your own original code (the way you originally intended). I'm pretty confident it will work!

Comment: Quick question though, what is the reduction for (tf.reduce), I mean, aren't we minimizing the cross_entropy through the optimizer??

Comment: Good question. As I understand it, the intention is to minimize the cost you calculated. You can do it in many ways. The function tf.reduce_mean just returns the mean from whatever you added as input. I think you can do it with other functions as well (eg tf.reduce_max). Try them out in the cost and see how it works.

Comment: Another question, if you don't mind. Uhm, like right now, I am only training my model and it keeps getting between 94 to 96 percent. (1) How do I increase the accuracy, are more hidden layers needed to achieve this? (2) Is it possible to load my own data into the model and it prints out what that data is? For example if I hand write the number 8, can I load it into the model then it prints "This number is 8", according to how accurate it is of course.

Comment: (1) That's the hard question! There is no one answer to this. You may find yourself testing many different configurations (number of layers, how wide each layer is). Maybe going as far as changing the type of neural network you're applying.
(2) There definitely is a way! Once you have trained a neural network you can save the graph and its parameters. Then, to apply it to new data coming in you load your graph and apply it! I've never done it myself, but I sense it's not as hard as it seems.

Comment: I will find out how its done, Thank you once again, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/temp/data/", one_hot = True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

#height x width

x = tf.placeholder('float',[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,n_nodes_hl1])),
    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
    hidden_2_layer =       {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1,n_nodes_hl2])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
    hidden_3_layer =    {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2,n_nodes_hl3])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
     output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3,n_classes])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']),hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']),hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']),hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output


def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(   tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction,labels=y))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x,epoch_y  = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _,epoch_c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += epoch_c
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of ', hm_epochs, 'loss: ', epoch_loss)
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))



train_neural_network(x)
```

Comment: Add some explanation about the solution you posted.